# How to get the standard error stream for a ProcessObject?

Tags: external-calls, streams

When you run an external program using `RunProcess`, the program will run to completion and you will receive an association containing the exit code, stuff that went to standard error, and stuff that went to standard output. Useful stuff!

However, if you start a process with `StartProcess` and get a returned `ProcessObject`, you can read from standard output just by using `ReadString` and friends with the process object itself, but there seems to be no way to get to standard output. This seems like a strange limitation. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ProcessConnection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProcessConnection.html).

```
process = StartProcess[$SystemShell]

ProcessConnection[process, "StandardError"]
```

This returns an [`InputStream`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputStream.html) object. `"StandardInput"` and `"StandardOutput"` can be retrieved the same way.

Comment: I did not know this. I researched this right now.